# Javascript - file organization with intellisense

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

New to Javascript, and trying to get to grips with the best way to create a productive workflow for well-organized code in visual studio.

All I want is the ability to define a module/class/variable/whatever you want to call it in one file, and reference it in another file.

circle.js:

```
var circle = {
     BeACircle: function(circleness) {
         ...
     }
}
```

default.js:

```
...
import("circle.js");
circle.BeACircle(10);
```

I would naturally like Intellisense to function as expected, showing me the contents of circle and such as I type.

What is the best way to set this up?

Comment: One of possible approaches https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/04/20/using-requirejs-with-visual-studio/

Comment: While it's a valid approach, I'm hoping for something a bit cleaner. I might be a purist, but I really don't want to have to nest all of the code that comes after each require statement in a callback.

Comment: Are you referring to RequireJS as such? The AMD pattern behind it is considered clean enough to be widely accepted. Read more on that http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html. As far as I know the other possibility, the CommonJS-like module pattern, is not supported by VS that well.

Comment: Just to add another opinion to this, You could use Typescript. Although not pure Javascript. its more module/class based but should provide you with cleaner code and if your used to strongly typed languages, is very object orientated. Also it transpiles into javascript and is supported in visual studio.

here is a link : http://www.typescriptlang.org/

Comment: Correct. despite its merits, I intensely dislike the AMD pattern and would love to just use the ES6 import command: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import  But, since that doesn't appear to be fully supported by modern web browsers yet, I'm looking for an interim solution that would work as closely to that as possible, with Intellisense support.